# Which line(s) of my proof of $A\to (\neg A \to B)$ are not allowed in relevance logic?

Tags: logic

I am trying to understand relevance logic. Here I prove $A\to (\neg A \to B)$ (a form of the Principle of Explosion) using ordinary natural deduction. Which inference(s) here are not allowed in relevance logic and why?

1. $A\space\space$ (assume)
2. $\neg A\space\space$ (assume)
3. $\neg B\space\space$ (assume)
4. $A\land\neg A\space\space$ (intro $\land$, 1, 2)
5. $\neg\neg B\space\space$ (intro $\neg$, 3, 4)
6. $B\space\space$ (elim $\neg\neg$, 5)
7. $\neg A \to B\space\space$ (intro $\to$, 2, 6)
8. $A\to (\neg A \to B)\space\space$ (intro $\to$, 1, 7)

Comment: See Greg Restall, [Relevant and Substructural Logics](http://consequently.org/papers/HPPLrssl.pdf), page 20 : "We must do something to the rule for conjunction introduction to ban this
proof. The required emendation is to only allow conjunction introduction
when the two subproofs have exactly the same open assumptions."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What a bizarre restriction to place upon oneself! Thanks.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Can $A\to (\neg A \to B)$ be proven by other means in relevance logic? How about   $A \to (B \to A\land B$)?

Comment: I do not think so: in [Relevance Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-relevance/) $¬p → (p → q)$ is not valid.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What about $A \to (B \to A\land B)$? Can this really be rejected by serious scholars?